# Do I need to use the "Add Git" button in BlueMix?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops

I was working well sending changes by git to my project but today I see the button "Add Git", but my project was in a git repository, I can see my code on the bluemix page with my last changes sent to Git, but I see the "Add Git" button. Do I have a problem? how can I resolve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: you can get support asking here -- developer.ibm.com/answers or opening a ticket (developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support). Your question unfortunately does not provide enough information for someone to help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bluemix DevOps Services to build and deploy the app from its Git repository into Bluemix, then you can remove the app from Bluemxi and deploy again from Bluemix DevOps Services. The link to Git repository should come up again.

If you never used Bluemix DevOps Services to build and deploy the app (it is not a requirement, just an option) then it is normal you see that link with the possibility to create a new project in Bluemix Devops Services.

Comment: Before, I saw a link of URL of Git, but now I see a button "Add Git" like my application broke the configuration con Git repository in BlueMix.

Comment: I didn't do nothing and today I can see my URL of GIT correctly, I suppose something did on bluemix DevOps yesterday, because today I can work normally. Thanks.